# cross session variable php to asp.net (c#)

Tags: c#, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to have a PHP login form store a session variable for an asp.net (c#) web-application, laying on the same server.

The PHP logic is pretty simple: email, password, human proof and send button.

Once the user has been found in the MySQL database, then the system should create a session variable for the asp.net application.

I was thinking about jquery ajax or post, so that if the call is successful and the result is true, it makes another ajax call as a callback to an asp.net file, to store the session.

Being not an expert in .net, I do not know what do address to make that work. I mean, I have a .cs file with some methods inside it and I wrote one that takes a post variable and puts it in a session variable.

What I do not know is how to address that .cs file (I supposed I can't directly) and invoke that specific method.

Any suggestion?

Comment: First of all the session is stored in the navigator, with an id to access it, it varies from one navigator to an another, in asp.net, sessions values are stored in an array object, you can access it by calling "Session ['variable']", notice well that the session array is an object array, so you must cast the object.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the session object and the casting. I don t know how to set a session using a jquery function valled from a php script. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a static method in your ASP.Net page, and then use a `ScriptManager` control on your ASP.Net page with `EnablePageMethods=true`.  Then you can call the method from JavaScript as `PageMethods.MethodName(...)`.

Alternatively if the domain is the same it may be easier for you to set a cookie from within PHP and then access that within your ASP.Net page load code, if you can satisfy yourself that this won't expose a security vulnerability,